# Place Picker API getName shows LatLng when clicking SELECT THIS LOCATION

Tags: java, android, google-places, gmsplacepicker

[I am using Place Picker API to get placename, address, phone, website. As seen on the first picture when i click a place on the map it shows the place name and address and when selected the results show in a form company name, address, phone number etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hpA4.jpg)!

[When i click SELECT THIS LOCATION it shows latlng coordinates and places them in the form in the company name edittext. It basically means that place.getName() gets you the places name when selecting a place, and latlng when clicking SELECT THIS location.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0ukm.jpg)

How can i make the selected coordinates to go in another field and not under place.getName()?